# Excel styling error in C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have one project using below code and working properly.

```
oSheet.Cells[1, i].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightSlateGrey
```

But I copied this into a new project and added the same reference, but gives an error.

Full code :

```
    Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;Excel.Application oXL; 
    Excel._Workbook oWB; 
    Excel._Worksheet oSheet; 
    Excel.Range oRng; 
    oXL = new Excel.Application(); 
    oXL.UserControl = false; 
    oWB = (oXL.Workbooks.Add("")); 
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet; 
int currentRow = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    oSheet.Cells[currentRow, 2] = "123"; 
    oSheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Interior.Color =  Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue;
currentRow++;
}
    //Make the headers bold
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
     {
       oSheet.Cells[3, i].Interior.Color = 
       Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightSlateGrey;
    }
```

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Interior' and no extension
>   method 'Interior' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you post the full code where you are using it along with the reference? are you using office interop?

Comment: yes I am using interop 

    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;Excel.Application oXL;
    Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    Excel.Range oRng;
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    oWB = (oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
    oSheet.Cells[currentRow, 2] = "123";
    oSheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue;

Comment: Can you add the code in the question please  .. difficult to read here

Comment: what is the value of `currentRow` here ? it's not present in the code. The `Interior` property exists in `Worksheet.Range` object. So if `oSheet.Cells[currentRow, 2]` does not return a valid Range then it would not be possible to use `Interior` on it . For example `oSheet.Cells` returns a `Range` object which contains all the cells in the active sheet.

Comment: Hi Niladri I added the remaining code in the initial question area

Comment: oSheet.Range[currentRow, 1].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue; solved the issue. Thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: you are welcome .. I suspected that `Cell` is not pointing to a proper range